# How to filter one-to-many relations with query builder

Tags: node.js, query-builder, typeorm

I have

```
@Entity('procedures')
export class ProcedureEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToMany(type => MediaFileEntity, media => media.procedure, {
        cascade: true
    })
    files: MediaFileEntity[];

};
```

and

```
@Entity('media_files')
export class MediaFileEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    deletedAt: Date;

    @ManyToOne(type => ProcedureEntity, procedure => procedure.files)
    procedure: ProcedureEntity;

};
```

Does anybody know how do I create a query builder so that I get all the procedures, but with media files that have `deletedAt` NULL ?

I'm trying to do

```
const procedures = await this.procedureRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("procedure")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("procedure.doctor", "doctor")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("procedure.patient", "patient")
    .innerJoin('procedure.files', 'mediaFile', 'mediaFile.deletedAt IS NULL')
    .where("(patient.id = :id OR doctor.id = :doctorId)", { id: user.id, doctorId: user.id })
    .andWhere('procedure.deletedAt IS NULL')
    .getMany();
```

but I get `Cannot find name 'where'`. Which is odd, because `this.procedureRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("procedure")` is also a `SelectQueryBuilder<ProcedureEntity>` and so is `this.procedureRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("procedure")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("procedure.doctor", "doctor")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("procedure.patient", "patient")
    .innerJoin('procedure.files', 'mediaFile', 'mediaFile.deletedAt IS NULL');`

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Funny enough, I already had the answer. But I'm gonna leave it here anyway, for posterity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error. You have semicolon after `innerJoin`. Is this the cause of the error?